# how to detect the number of usb devices picking up video

Tags: usb, webcam, detect

Please help. If I have multiple devices connected via usb to my computer, is it possible to detect which of those devices are web cameras and count them?

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and enter

```
lsusb
```

Maybe the description tells you something about the functionality.
I get this output:

```
$ lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b064 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c06a Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 03f0:0324 Hewlett-Packard SK-2885 keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

and with this see that I have three input devices (HID): 1 Keyboard and 2 mices.